# (Bootstrap 3) How do you center a group of buttons when the device is extra small

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically, I want group of buttons to be bellow the jumbotron and centered when the device is extra small but I can't managed to center them when the device width is xs. They just go to the left. Please help.

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron col-sm-8 col-lg-8" >
            <h1>Hello, soldiers</h1>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectAspernatur amet obcaecati perferendis autem quas, animi, velit. Animi sit, recusandae magnam adipisci autem veniam ex repudiandae doloribus iure!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-8 text-center">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 5</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0` classes to your group of buttons :

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-offset-0 text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 4</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 5</button>
</div>
```

This will add two empty columns before your group.
The `col-sm-offset-0` class is here to remove these columns on larger screens.

[**Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/kPXrZw1LZa)

Answer (score 0):

*Just have to change the `col-xs-8` to `col-xs-12` class on your container.*

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/6P8XDyvhxY

**HTML**

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron col-sm-8 col-lg-8">
            <h1>Hello, soldiers</h1>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectAspernatur amet obcaecati perferendis autem quas, animi, velit. Animi sit, recusandae magnam adipisci autem veniam ex repudiandae doloribus iure!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group-vertical col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-12 text-center"> // <---- HERE
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 3</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 4</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button 5</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-8 text-center">
```

to:

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-center">
```